# Taking derivative of solution of ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I solved the following differential equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(a^2 (5+4\tanh( x))+b^2)y=0$$
using ParametricNDSolve and I want to use $\frac{d y}{dx}$ in further calculation so I wrote the following code

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + (a*a + b*b*(5 + 4 Tanh[x]))*y[x]==0,y[-10]==Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]], y'[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]]}, y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}] 
y1 = D[s[a, b],x]
```

but I am getting **$0$** as the output. I know if I use constant value instead of $a,b$ for example

```
y1 = D[s[.1, .1],x]
```

then I get proper result but what I really want is $y^{'}(a,b)$ so what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {y''[x] + (a*a + b*b*(5 + 4 Tanh[x]))*y[x] == 0, 
   y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]], 
   y'[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]]};
```

If you are looking for an analytic result you must use [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html). However, it is quite slow.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Short[sol = DSolve[eqns, y[x], x][[1]] // Simplify]]
```

[image]

The solution is quite long and complicated.

```
sol // LeafCount

(* 12470 *)
```

The derivative is then

```
Short[sol2 = D[sol, x]]
```

[image]

```
sol2 // LeafCount

(* 70958 *)

Plot[
 Evaluate[Abs[y'[x] /. sol2 /. {a -> 0.1`30, b -> 0.1`30}]],
 {x, -5, 25}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (a*a + b*b*(5 + 4 Tanh[x]))*y[x] == 0, y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]],y'[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]]},y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]
```

The derivative follows to

```
Y[ .1,.1]'[0]
(*-0.0271645 - 0.143655 I*)
```

Comment: you miss my point I'm not interested in calculating $y'(.1,.1)$ what I really want is $y'(a,b)$

Comment: No I didn't miss: ParametricNDSolve gives a pseudoparametric result, which only can be evaluated if you provide explicit parameters!

Answer (score 0):

What about introducing a second function z with `y'[x] == z[x]` and solving for both y and z.

```
s2 = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == z[x], 
        z'[x] + (a*a + b*b*(5 + 4 Tanh[x]))*y[x] == 0, 
        y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]], 
        z[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a*a + b*b]]}, 
           {y, z}, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]
```

(Since `ParametricNDSolve`is not implemented in my Version 8.0, I can't test it.)